# How does the Swift runtime handle tuples?

Tags: swift

I've been trying to swap 2 objects without using a temp value, which be done like so:

```
var a = "Hello, "
var b = "world!"

(a,b) = (b,a)

a    // "world!"
b    // "Hello, "
```

Does anyone know how the language is doing this, is the second tuple (b,a) stored in memory to allow the first one to reassign itself, or does it do it all by switching references?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It does it safely and reliably so what do you care? If you are really worried, use the `swap` global function. But I've never had any trouble with tuple swap; it's just like Ruby.

Comment: It **does not** switch references for value types like `String`.

Comment: You can confirm this by adding `NSLog("%p %p", a, b)` **before and after** the switch.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of "switching" does the following:

- **Replaces** the pointers for **class types**

  ```
  var classA = NSString(string: "foo")
  var classB = NSString(string: "bar")

  NSLog("%p %p", classA, classB) // 0x7fecd351def0 0x7fecd341cc30
  (classA, classB) = (classB, classA)
  NSLog("%p %p", classA, classB) // 0x7fecd341cc30 0x7fecd351def0
  ```
- **Creates new** values (copies) for **value types**

  ```
  var valueA = "baz"
  var valueB = "qux"

  NSLog("%p %p", valueA, valueB) // 0x7fecd34201b0 0x7fecd34211e0
  (valueA, valueB) = (valueB, valueA)
  NSLog("%p %p", valueA, valueB) // 0x7fecd351c880 0x7fecd351de90
  ```

Comment: You're completely right at the logical level, but bear in mind that a) strings are also partly like reference types with copy-on-write functionality, and b) the compiler can optimize so in practice the answer to the question "exactly what does this do" is "depends on a lot of things" (also, logging changes what the compiler might be doing since you're forcing it to perform operations that could perhaps have been optimized away – for example, chances are with the original code, the value for `b` would actually be put straight into `a` &vv)

Comment: Yes, we don't know that for sure, that's just theory. P.S. Love your blog! :)